# Javascript validation for DD/MM/YY

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, html

I need to check for this in javascript. So i need to pass in something like this

```
var validdate = ^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$;
```

This is throwing a "expected expression" error in VS. Whats wrong with that expression? Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error, because in JS a RegExp literal starts and ends with a slash (/)

```
var validdate = /^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[.\/-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[.\/-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$/;
```

Comment: You can change your regexp to /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([.\/-])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\2([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$/ It does the same, but is shorter by some characters and also prevents setting a date to 12/12-2011 (look at the different separators)

Comment: Also, if you want to have leading zeros mandatory, remove the question marks after the zeros (0?)

Comment: Hey ValianthX, if this solved your question, please mark it as the answer.